# Angular set selected option not working

Tags: angularjs, select

I want to set selected `Audio` option but its not working. Following is my HTML:

```
<form ng-app='test' ng-controller='testController'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model='event.type'>
        <option disbaled> Select</option>
        <option>IM</option>
        <option>Audio</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var testApp = angular.module('test', []);

testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.event.type = 'Audio';//not working
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmpb0j7x/)

Any idea?

Comment: 1) disABled ;)
2) <option selected>Audio</option> works, if it can be done not in controller

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/jmpb0j7x/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use

$scope.event = {} as below

```
var testApp = angular.module('test', []);

testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.event ={};
    $scope.event.type = 'Audio';//not working
});
```

OR

```
testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.event = {'type':'Audio'};//not working
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jmpb0j7x/1/)

Comment: Its working in Jsfiddle but not in my js file :-(. Any other option of this?

Comment: can i see your controller?

Comment: Sure but my controller having lot of other code also :-(

Comment: better to use your model as single element not as json element. if you need json as like your using do that in controller for audio ng-model="event"

Comment: I can't change it now because i am using `event.type` everywhere. Thanks now i have solved my issue with another solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is syntax error in your code while declaring object event.Right syntax is given below.

```
testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.event ={};
    $scope.event.type = 'Audio';//not working
});
```

You have to use ng-selected directive of angular to make any option selected by default.

```
<option disbaled> Select</option>
<option>IM</option>
<option ng-selected="true">Audio</option>
```

Comment: Superb `ng-selected="true"` works perfectly. This is what i was looking for.